# Merge 2 sorted arrays with the same size without extra space?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
int size = 10;
int *data = new int[size];

int *array_1 = &data[0];
int *array_2 = &data[size/2];

//fill array_1 and array_2 with data

sort(array_1, array_1+size/2);
sort(array_2, array_2+size/2);

//now, is it possible to merge the 2 sorted arrays?
```

For example if `array_1 = {1, 4, 7}` and `array_2 = {3, 5, 6}`

I am trying to make `data = {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`

Comment: [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge)

Comment: @NathanOliver: How does the `std::merge` work? Is complexity O(N) without extra space?

Comment: @NathanOliver That would be a good general solution, but I think the contract of std::merge (the destination range does not overlap the input ranges) is being violated by OP's code.

Comment: @SuperHeroY the link I provided covers that.

Comment: @Xirema You are correct.  I did not notice both "arrays" were pointers into the same array.  In this scenario I would this just a [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) on `data` would do the trick.

Comment: It's possible but complicated. This is not something that you want to do in practice. (Undoubtedly there's a duplicate question somewhere...)

Comment: @David Eisenstat: I am looking for the fastest way to merge those arrays. What do you reccomend?

Comment: If you've already got an array of data, just sort the original array. For what reason are you trying to sort the two halves separately?

Comment: @Xirema: I am sorting the pieces using multiple threads to make it faster.

Comment: Is this an implementation of merge sort?

Comment: @Xirema: No, I am trying to make a fast sort function to sort huge arrays very often.

Comment: Allocate a scratch array.

Comment: If you want an efficient parallel sort, you should really use a parallel sort algorithm. Doing multiple serial sorts and merging the results will be less efficient than a true parallel sort. Standard C++ does not yet have any parallel algorithms, though they are in the process of standardization. In the meantime there are a number of third party solutions including Microsoft's PPL, Intel's TBB, Nvidia Thrust and more.

Comment: @mattnewport: Interesting point. Can you explain why calling std::sort many times and then using a parallel merge function will be slower than a true parallel sort?

Comment: Well if that was efficient, why would anyone bother researching parallel sort algorithms? You're asking a different question in your comment though. In your question you are talking about independent serial sorts done in parallel followed by a serial merge. In your comment you ask about a parallel merge. With a serial merge, you put all the merging work on the merging thread which means Amdahl's law is going to bite you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want std::inplace_merge. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/inplace_merge/

Comment: So this actually binary searches the 2nd array for every element... Not ideal for real world usage but awnsers my question. Thanks!

Comment: @SuperHeroY: Notice the complexity is: "If enough extra memory is available, linear in the distance between first and last: Performs N-1 comparisons and up to twice that many element moves."